# Ruby: Who is self inside a block during yielding?

Tags: ruby, scope, self

Maybe this is a stupid question, but I can't figure it out. I have a "feeling" why `main` is `self` during execution of the block. But I don't have a solid explanation for it.

It seems that the question who is `self` depends on the context where the block is defined. Is this right?

Can anyone explain it to me?

```
?> class Klass
?>   def yld
?>     yield
?>   end
>> end

>>
>> o1 = Klass.new
>> o2 = Klass.new
>>
?> o1.yld {
?>   o2.yld {
?>     p self
?>   }
>> }
main
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`self` doesn't change because of a block. The reason you get `main` is because you are calling `yld` from the main context:

```
p self #=> main
o1.yld {
  p self #=> main
  o2.yld {
    p self #=> main
  }
  p self #=> main
}
p self #=> main
```

However, `self` can be changed explicitly, e.g. via [`instance_eval`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/BasicObject.html#instance_eval-method):

```
def foo(&block)
  "hello".instance_eval(&block)
end

p self #=> main
foo {
  p self   #=> "hello"
  p size   #=> 5
  p upcase #=> "HELLO"
}
p self #=> main
```

In the above code, `self` is changed to the string instance `"hello"` during the block.